# XHR upload and the moment the upload begins

Tags: javascript, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

I'm attempting to find a way when an upload is initiated with XHR so I can do something; I looked around and read that `.loadstart` was for when the request starts (which means what exactly?) and this is what I had:

```
function processUpload(file, postName, onLoadCallback, onErrorCallBack, onProgressCallBack, startCallBack)
{    
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fD = new FormData();

    for(var i = 0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        xhr.open("POST", "PATHHERE");

        xhr.loadstart = startCallBack;

        xhr.onload =  onLoadCallback;

        xhr.onerror = onErrorCallBack;

        xhr.upload.onprogress = onProgressCallBack;

        fD.append(postName, file[i]);
        xhr.send(fD);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm unsure if a for loop is the best way of going about doing multiple file uploads. I feel as though that could get heavy on the site. What is the better method of doing that?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question

Comment: It's pointless to reassign the handlers over and over again; it's the same object, so they don't change between iterations. Primarily however your problem will be that not all browsers support those events, and you're not assigning a handler for the "readystatechange" event.  Also, you're using the same XHR object over and over again, which is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: Cool, that I didn't know! Thanks for the heads up. As for "readystatechange," what do you mean by that?

Comment: So what is up to date. It would be great to further explain what you're saying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request starts when you call send. You may want to queue you files to limit concurrent uploads. Take a look at already existing [file uploader](https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader) implementation.

Look into [source code](https://github.com/devbridge/html5-file-uploader/blob/master/Html5UploadDemo/Scripts/src/html5Upload.js) for the html5 uploader if you want to write your own.

Comment: Is there a call back to the send function?